# jQuery Div content change monitor event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

A script (**A**) on my website updates a certain div (id="**divA**"). Another script (**B**) changes something in that div when the page is loaded. (that works) However, the divA should also be updated after script A is fired and updates the divA. Get it?

I've written a working jQuery function (aScript) that perfectly works as the page is loaded.

```
$('#divA').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
   console.log("Change Detected");
   $(this).aScript();
});
```

As soon as the divA is updated by A, I see over 1000+ logs in the browser. Apparently 'DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved' is executed over 1000 times for each Node in the div that is updated.

Is there a way that I can check whether divA is updated by A and *afterwards* run B? Without changing script A (no rights for that).

Comment: You should be very careful to avoid loops here. If script A updates itself in a function it could trigger an endless loop.

Comment: That happend ;)  Therefore my question

Comment: Look into mutation observers.